# Potential deadlock in thread-safe stack C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

In the book "Concurrency in Action", there's an implementation of thread-safe stack where mutex is acquired/locked upon entering pop() and empty() functions like shown below:

```
class threadsafe_stack {
   private:
      std::stack<T> data;
      mutable std::mutex m;
   public:
      //...
      void pop(T& value) {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
         if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
         value = std::move(data.top());
         data.pop();
      }

      bool empty() const {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
         return data.empty();
      }
};
```

My question is, how does this code not run into a deadlock, when a thread, that has acquired the lock upon entering pop() is calling empty() which is protected by mutex as well? If lock() is called by the thread that already owns the mutex, isn't that undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does this code not run into a deadlock, when a thread, that has acquired the lock upon entering pop() is calling empty() which is protected by mutex as well?

Because you are not calling `empty` member function of `threadsafe_stack` but you are calling empty() of class `std::stack<T>`. If the code would be:

```
void pop(T& value) 
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if(empty()) // instead of data.empty()
        throw empty_stack();
    value = std::move(data.top());
    data.pop();
}
```

Then, it would be [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock):

> If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined: for example, the program may deadlock. An implementation that can detect the invalid usage is encouraged to throw a std::system_error with error condition resource_deadlock_would_occur instead of deadlocking.

Learn about [recursive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) and [shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) mutex.

Answer (score 1):

You would be correct if `pop` would call `this->empty`. Locking the same mutex twice via a `std::lock_guard` is undefined behavior unless the locked mutex is a recursive one.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard) on the constructor (the one that is used in the example code):

> Effectively calls m.lock(). The behavior is undefined if m is not a recursive mutex and the current thread already owns m.

For the sake of completeness, there is a second constructor:

```
lock_guard( mutex_type& m, std::adopt_lock_t t );
```

which

> Acquires ownership of the mutex m without attempting to lock it. The behavior is undefined if the current thread does not own m.

However, `pop` calls `data.empty` and this is the method of the private member, not the member function `empty` of `threadsafe_stack`. There is no problem in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you mean, I guess you mean calling `pop` and `empty` sequentially in the same thread? Like in

```
while(!x.empty()) x.pop();
```

`std::lock_guard` follows RAII. This means the constructor

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
```

will acquire/lock the mutex and the destructor (when `lock` goes out of scope) will release/unlock the mutex again. So it's unlocked at the next function call.

Inside `pop` only `data.empty()` is called, which is not protected by a mutex. Calling `this->empty()` inside `pop` would indeed result in undefined behaviour.